# script not displaying the filename that exist in the dir

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
file=/home/yaal/temp/hatch/*;
if [[ -f  $file ]]; then
 echo $file
else 
echo "No files found"
fi
```

I have files under hatch dir but it is displaying "No files found". why is it?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you'd want to use `for loop` to check if file exists because the pathname expansion does not happen inside `[[ ... ]]`. Use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /home/yaal/temp/hatch/*; do
    if [[ -f  $file ]]; then
        echo $file
    else 
       echo "No files found"
    fi
done
```

Comment: `bash` can use regular expressions, but in a different context.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. Corrected the answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Pathname expansion does not occur on the right-hand side of a non-array variable assignment, so `file` contains a literal `*`, not a list of file names. Pathname expansion is not performed inside `[[ ... ]]` either, so you are asking if there is a file named `*` exists in /home/yaal/temp/hatch`.

If you just want to know if there is at least one file (excluding files starting with `.`) in `hatch`, try

```sh
for f in /home/yaal/temp/hatch/*; do
    if [[ -f $f ]]; then
        echo "$file"
    else
        echo "No files found"
    fi
    break
done
```

You can also fill an array, then check if it is empty or not:

```
files=( /home/yaal/temp/hatch/* )
if (( ${#files[@]} > 0 )); then
    echo "${files[0]}"   # First file found
else
    echo "No files found"
fi
```

If you do want to consider file names beginning with `.`, either use `shopt -s dotglob`, or use two patterns `/home/yaal/temp/hatch/* /home/yaal/temp/hatch/.*`.